# Почему не правильно отображается css?

Tags: html, css

Прстой акардеон. Хочу при раскрывающем списке разбить на две колонке 
Но при использовании **float:left** `.col-md-6{width:33;float:left}`
Оно западает за другой пункт

Показано в демо

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('.accordion').on('click', '.titlle', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.titlle').not($(this)).siblings('.content').slideUp('normal');
        $('.titlle').not($(this)).removeClass("active");
        $(this).siblings('.content').slideToggle('normal');
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
    $('.accordion .content').hide();
    $('.accordion .active').next().slideDown('normal');
})();
```

```css
section.accordion {
    margin: 0 0 15px 10px;
    padding: 1px 1px;
}
.titlle {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 30px;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
       padding: 8px 20px 10px 52px;
    position: relative;

}
.col-md-6{width:33;float:left}
.titlle a{color:#000!important;}
.active  {
    background: #ffb900 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.active a{color:#fff!important;}

.content p {
    border-left: 1px dashed #8c8c8c;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
   .content {padding: 20px 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="accordion">
<div class="titlle"><a href="#">Главная</a></div>
<div class="content">

<div class="col-md-6">
текст текст
тексттекст
<img src="//biznessystem.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/mediafajly.png" alt="Коробчатого сечения, сварная балка из листового проката" width="272" height="222" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-839" /> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
текст текст
тексттекст
<img src="//biznessystem.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/mediafajly.png" alt="Коробчатого сечения, сварная балка из листового проката" width="272" height="222" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-839" /> 
</div>
</div>
</section>

<section class="accordion">
<div class="titlle"><a href="#">лектрическая</a></div>
<div class="content">

Renewal of Mission Labour Card (Application+ Submission) 3

</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div` с классом row пропущен, да и в этом варианте `float: left` не нужен

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  $('.accordion').on('click', '.titlle', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.titlle').not($(this)).siblings('.content').slideUp('normal');
    $('.titlle').not($(this)).removeClass("active");
    $(this).siblings('.content').slideToggle('normal');
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
  $('.accordion .content').hide();
  $('.accordion .active').next().slideDown('normal');
})();
```

```css
section.accordion {
  margin: 0 0 15px 10px;
  padding: 1px 1px;
}

.titlle {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 20px 10px 52px;
  position: relative;
}

.col-md-6 {
  width: 33;
}

.titlle a {
  color: #000!important;
}

.active {
  background: #ffb900 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.active a {
  color: #fff!important;
}

.content p {
  border-left: 1px dashed #8c8c8c;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="accordion">
  <div class="titlle"><a href="#">Главная</a></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        текст текст тексттекст
        <img src="//biznessystem.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/mediafajly.png" alt="Коробчатого сечения, сварная балка из листового проката" width="272" height="222" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-839" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        текст текст тексттекст
        <img src="//biznessystem.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/mediafajly.png" alt="Коробчатого сечения, сварная балка из листового проката" width="272" height="222" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-839" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="accordion">
  <div class="titlle"><a href="#">лектрическая</a></div>
  <div class="content">

    Renewal of Mission Labour Card (Application+ Submission) 3

  </div>
</section>
```